# Creating DataGrid column tooltip entirely in code behind

Tags: c#, silverlight, datagrid

I'm trying to create datagrid tooltip entirely in code behind file. 
Tooltip XAML code looks like this:

```
<data:DataGrid>
<data:DataGrid.Columns>
    <data:DataGridTextColumn Header="My Header">
        <data:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
            <Style TargetType="dataprimitives:DataGridColumnHeader">
                <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                                <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                    <ToolTip Content="My Tooltip"></ToolTip>
                                </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                            </ContentControl>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </data:DataGridTextColumn.HeaderStyle>
    </data:DataGridTextColumn>
</data:DataGrid.Columns>
```

I'm stuck at the `<Setter Property="ContentTemplate">`. My current code:

```
                Style style = new Style();
                style.TargetType = typeof(DataGridColumnHeader);
                Setter setter = new Setter();
                setter.Property = DependencyProperty.Register("ContentTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(FrameworkElement), null);
```

Anyone could show me an example of implementing this part in code behind:

```
<Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                                    <ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                        <ToolTip Content="My Tooltip"></ToolTip>
                                    </ToolTipService.ToolTip>
                                </ContentControl>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Once you have got the handle for the column to which you want to add the tooltip then you try below.

```
var style = new Style(typeof(DataGridColumnHeader));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(ToolTipService.ToolTipProperty, "Customer Name"));
```

Now that you have defined you tooltip value then you can set the HeaderStyle property of the column something like this...

```
dgCustDetails.Columns[0].HeaderStyle = style;
```

where dgCustDetails is the datagrid's name.

Comment: Tested and approved for Winui3

Answer (score 2):

```
Style stylecell = new Style(typeof(DataGridCell));

Binding descriptionbinding = new Binding("SRNO") { StringFormat = "{0}" };

stylecell.Setters.Add(newSetter(ToolTipService.ToolTipProperty,descriptionbinding));

gridItem.Columns[0].CellStyle = stylecell;
```